Date base data sheet generation from master sheet
I have one google sheet with two tabs one the master named "All Week Revenue - MasterSheet" where the importrange data will get updated date wise regularly of our sales team. I need the individual sales count along the total sales volume (TSV) and deposit amount (DP Amount) to a new tab named "DAILY SALES COUNT". based on the dates.
here is the sample link for the google sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b9w61Xa9nMt2bJAHWHBBHE2j7LzF7_E1GcCWWcqAo6U/edit#gid=820688094
I have mentioned how the output should be in "DAILY SALES COUNT" tab.
From master sheet I need only info from cell A, B, D, G & H.
where A & B are name of Manager and sales person, D is TSV, G is DP Amount and H is Dates.
I need the count of TSV column D followed by values of D and G
I tried pivot however is gives me the count of per day sales but the TSV and DP amount is showing only the grand total and not date wise.
Tried Vlookup with my little knowledge not of no use.


Here's one approach added to your test sheet:
=let(Σ,'All Week Revenue - MasterSheet'!A2:H12, a,index(Σ,,1),b,index(Σ,,2),d,index(Σ,,4),g,index(Σ,,7),h,index(Σ,,8),Λ,sort(unique(tocol(h,1)),1,),
 x,vstack(,{"MANAGER","BDA E-MAIL"},unique(filter({a,b},a<>""))),
 reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(x)),lambda(i,c,ifna(vstack(i,let(Δ,chooserows(x,c), hstack(Δ,reduce(torow(,1),Λ,lambda(f,q,hstack(f,if(+Δ="",hstack(text(q,"mm-dd-e"),,),if(+Δ="MANAGER",hstack("Count","TSV","DP"),let(z,join(,Δ),index(let(Ξ,hstack(countifs(h,q,a&b,z),sum(ifna(filter(d,h=q,a&b=z))),sum(ifna(filter(g,h=q,a&b=z)))),if(Ξ=0,,Ξ))))))))))))))))



Change the range from 'All Week Revenue - MasterSheet'!A2:H12 to 'All Week Revenue - MasterSheet'!A2:H when you are implementing it in real.


this is how i need it but when appling in real sheet this is showing an error. #REF! - Result wan not automatically expanded. please insert more columns. I have inserted more that 100,000 column still the error shows up

Recreate the error scenario in your test sheet so that we can see what's happening exactly...

thats becoz my data is huge starting from dec 2023 to date. so google sheet has a limitation of total cells to use. I have split the data into qtrly basis and created mutiple tabs and that is working fine. Thanks for your help.

This is working fine. Can we format it also like per day information with common border. Example 12-06-2024 under that count, TSV and DP. all this should be with single boder. Just to see the seperation datewise.

=let(Σ,'All Week Revenue - MasterSheet'!A943:H, a,index(Σ,,1),b,index(Σ,,2),d,index(Σ,,4),g,index(Σ,,7),h,index(Σ,,8),Λ,sort(unique(tocol(h,1)),1,),
x,vstack(,{"MANAGER","BDA E-MAIL"},unique(filter({a,b},a<>""))),
reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(x)),lambda(i,c,ifna(vstack(i,let(Δ,chooserows(x,c), hstack(Δ,reduce(torow(,1),Λ,lambda(f,q,hstack(f,if(+Δ="",hstack(text(q,"dd-mm-e"),,),if(+Δ="MANAGER",hstack("Count","TSV","DP"),let(z,join(,Δ),index(let(Ξ,hstack(countifs(h,q,a&b,z),sum(ifna(filter(d,h=q,a&b=z))),sum(ifna(filter(g,h=q,a&b=z)))),if(Ξ=0,,Ξ)))))))))))))))) how can I make it asc oder

based on first coloumn. (Managers)

CAN WE GET DATA BASED ON MONTH WISE ONLY AND INSTED OF DATE WISE. SO TSV AND DP AMOUNT WILL THE SUM OF ALL THE MONTHS VALUE AND TOTAL COUNT OF TSV

this would be done like:
=LET(r, A2:Q10, p, "where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col8",
 l, QUERY(r, "select Col1,Col2,count(Col3) "&p),
 c, QUERY(r, "select count(Col3) "&p), 
 t, QUERY(r, "select sum(Col4) "&p), 
 d, QUERY(r, "select sum(Col7) "&p), 
 {CHOOSECOLS(l, 1, 2), TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE({c, t, d}), 1, 0))})


you can change A2:Q10 to your range or directly IMPORTRANGE(...)
with custom headers:
=LET(r, A2:Q10, p, "where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 pivot Col8",
 l, QUERY(r, "select Col1,Col2,count(Col3) "&p),
 c, QUERY(r, "select count(Col3) "&p), 
 t, QUERY(r, "select sum(Col4) "&p), 
 d, QUERY(r, "select sum(Col7) "&p), 
 f, {CHOOSECOLS(l, 1, 2), TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE({c, t, d}), 1, 0))}, 
 {INDEX(f,1); {"MANAGER", "BDA E-MAIL", 
 TOROW(REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(TOCOL(OFFSET(r,,7,,1), 1))), 
 LAMBDA(a, b, {{"Count"; "TSV"; "DP"}; a})), 1)}; QUERY(f, "offset 1", )})



CAN WE GET DATA BASED ON MONTH WISE  ONLY AND NOT DATE WISE
